# python: how can I get a new value in round robin style every time i invoke the script

Tags: python, persistence, round-robin

I have a file called subnets which contains a list of available subnets in the system.
I want that my script should return to me one subnet at each script invocation, in round robin style.

Example:

subnets file:

```
subnet1
subnet2
subnet3
```

expected output:

```
python next_available_subnet.py    
output: subnet1

python next_available_subnet.py    
output: subnet2

python next_available_subnet.py    
output: subnet3

python next_available_subnet.py    
output: subnet1
```

How can I achieve this? I have tried global variables, iterators , but i lose the value by the time i invoke the script again and it always gives the same subnet as output.

Comment: You lose all variables when the script exits. You'll need to store a line number in the subnet file or in another file that you rewrite everytime through your script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other answers have pointed out, you will need some external way to provide persistency between executions. You could use a separate file, a database record, or some other long-running process.

However, you could also use the subnets file itself to provide the persistency. Just read the file, print the top value and then rotate its contents, ready for the next run.

This example uses a `deque` to implement the rotation:

```
import os
import collections

subnets_file = "subnets.txt"

# Load the subnets file into a deque
with open(subnets_file, 'r') as f:
    subnets = collections.deque(f.read().splitlines())

# Print the top subnet
print subnets[0]

# Rotate the subnets
subnets.rotate(-1)

# Save the rotated subnets
with open(subnets_file, 'w') as f:
    for s in subnets:
        f.write("%s\n" % s)
```

when run:

```
$ python next_available_subnet.py 
subnet1
$ python next_available_subnet.py 
subnet2
$ python next_available_subnet.py 
subnet3
$ python next_available_subnet.py 
subnet1
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your script ends, all data stored in memory will be wiped by the operating system. In your application, you need persistency across executions, which can be easily done using files or databases.

Simply save where you stopped in a hidden file (so as you don't accidentally delete) and read it before executing your script. Something like this:

```
import os

# define where to store the index of which file to use
index_file = '.index.txt'

# define your file list or read it from another file
files = ['subnet1', 'subnet2', 'subnet3']

# get your file
if os.path.isfile(index_file):
    with open(index_file) as fd:
        current_index = int(fd.read())
else:
    current_index = 0
current_file = files[current_index]

# process your file here

# increment current_index
current_index += 1
if current_index >= len(files):
    current_index = 0

# now save the last processed file
with open(index_file, 'w') as fd:
    fd.write(str(last_read))
```

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, you cannot achieve this with a single python script. You will need an additional file so the script remembers where it currently is. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

LOGFILE='logfile.txt'
SUBNETFILE='subnets.txt'

# Check if LOGFILE exists; if not, initialize it to -1
if not os.path.isfile(LOGFILE):
    with open(LOGFILE,'w') as f:
        f.write('-1')

# Get the current place from the LOGFILE
with open(LOGFILE,'r') as f:
    current = int(f.read().strip())

# Update the current place and read the line from SUBNETFILE
current += 1
with open(SUBNETFILE,'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
current = current%len(lines)

# Update LOGFILE and print the line from SUBNETFILE
with open(LOGFILE,'w') as f:
    f.write(str(current))
print lines[current]
```

Answer (score 0):

So, every time you run a script, variables and other values are stored in the main memory (ram) as long as the process is running they will stay there. In that case is impossible to achieve that without persisting values, because every time the process/script is finished it loses all the values stored in the memory.

You can persist values using python function open(). Read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) for more info. Hope that helps ;)